# how to add entitlement for iOS private api (MobileWifi.framework)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to use MobileWifi Framework to access `WiFi RSSI` data.

Link is here http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileWiFi.framework, but it says it needs the entitlement installed for this private framework.

I have no idea how to start with, anyone could give me a clue? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In the Target Summary tab check Use Entitlements File then add the wifi access key in there make the type a Boolean and set its value YES.

Note: You need to be jailbroken and have AppSync installed to use this private entitlement. Otherwise you'll get the error your app is signed with invalid entitlements.

Newer Xcode e.g. v11 now check if your provision file contains the entitlement (which it won't) but you can workaround this by signing in Xcode without the entitlement then signing again in a Build post-action (in Edit Scheme) as follows:

```
codesign -d --entitlements "${PROJECT_DIR}/MyApp/MyApp.entitlements" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/MyApp.app" -f -s "Apple Development"
```

You can figure out what to start off your entitlements file as using this in Terminal:

```
codesign -d --entitlements :- MyApp.app
```

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt Apple would let anything in the App Store that uses a private framework, but: `com.apple.wifi.manager-access`

Comment: The app is just for me.